# Link tags based on co-ordinates

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project(a family tree to be precise). I am still making sketches for the page so there's no code to show for testing.

The html page is going to have a background image of a tree and then the branches bearing pictures of different members of the family.

From the description it already shows that there will be a need to click different parts of the picture. So is there any way of placing images(carrying link tags) using the x and y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely place your images/elements at specific coordinates.

Your HTML/CSS would be in the tune of:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        position: relative; 
        background-image: url("tree-background.jpg");
        background-size: cover; 
      }

      #family-member-1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
      }

      #family-member-2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="link-1.html"
      ><img
        id="family-member-1"
        src="family-member-1.jpg"
        alt="Family Member 1"
    /></a>
    <a href="link-2.html"
      ><img
        id="family-member-2"
        src="family-member-2.jpg"
        alt="Family Member 2"
    /></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, I would not recommend this approach, for different reasons. Most importantly, you'll surely want your app to be *responsive* and it would be very tedious and inelegant to manage it manually with absolute/relative CSS code.
Instead, I'd recommend *CSS grid* or *flexbox* layouts, for which you can easily find many tutorials online.

Comment: welcome! please add the green tick to the answer if it helped you